# Can you design Windows RT apps in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know how I can design Windows RT apps on a Windows 7 PC?

I have Visual Studio 2012 installed and I have installed the Windows SDK kit but I still don't have any Windows store/mobile project types in Visual Studio.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows RT apps will only work on Windows 8/Windows 8 RT based Operating Systems. This also applies to Windows RT development.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately you can not develop any WinRT app on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can only create Windows Store apps on a Windows 8 PC.